# C# WinForms highlight treenode when treeview doesn't have focus

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I'm making an interface to edit scenarios for a game. Basically it consists of events, which have nested conditions and actions. So, I planned on using two treeviews - one for selecting the event, and other for selecting the condition/action inside the event to edit.

Now, you see, if I select an event (in left treeview) and then try to select something in the right treeview, the left treeview will stop showing the blue selection rectangle. This is obviously bad because now the user doesn't know which event is he editing!

The only way I found to retain some sort of information about what is the current selection is by using SelectedImageIndex, but that's only one little image that will be different.

Is there any other way to highlight the treenode while there is no focus on the treeview? I know I can just use Graphics.DrawRectangle or something, but I heard that drawing should be done in Paint event and treeview has no paint event... So I guess if I draw it on the event of losing focus, and then drag the form out of the screen or something, it will be "erased"?

Anyway, please tell me if you got an idea (other than using a separate icon for selected and not selected treenode).

Comment: the image you have posted is gone. do you have a copy somewhere? i'll remove the link in the meantime..

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `HideSelection` property on the `TreeView`.

**From MSDN:**

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected tree node remains highlighted even when the tree view has lost the focus.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection.aspx

**Code:**

```
TreeView.HideSelection = false;
```

Comment: actually on Windows7 with default color scheme this doesn't help - when treeview loses focus then selected node looks like deselected and I'm unable to see difference from another nodes.

Answer (score 18):

It is still shown but only in light grey which depending on your screen and current setup can be near in visible!

Override the OnDrawNode event. So you create and new class (call it "SpecialTreeView") an inherit from the Microsoft `TreeView` like `class SpecialTreeView : TreeView`. Then you add the following event override:

```
protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNodeStates treeState = e.State;
    Font treeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;

    // Colors.
    Color foreColor = e.Node.ForeColor;
    string strDeselectedColor = @"#6B6E77", strSelectedColor = @"#94C7FC";
    Color selectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strSelectedColor);
    Color deselectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strDeselectedColor);

    // New brush.
    SolidBrush selectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor);
    SolidBrush deselectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(deselectedColor);

    // Set default font color.
    if (foreColor == Color.Empty)
        foreColor = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;

    // Draw bounding box and fill.
    if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
    {
        // Use appropriate brush depending on if the tree has focus.
        if (this.Focused)
        {
            foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(selectedTreeBrush, e.Bounds);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                         foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
        else
        {
            foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(deselectedTreeBrush, e.Bounds);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                         foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Hot) == TreeNodeStates.Hot)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, hotFont, e.Bounds,
                                         System.Drawing.Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds,
                                         foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile the code and you should see "SpecialTreeView" in your tool box in the designer. Replace your TreeView with this new one using the same name and the only thing that will be different is the selection colours. When selected it will be `selectedColor`, when not selected the `deselectedColor`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it does, but only it doesnt :) Unless you set HideSelection to false, which is true by default (what for?... eh, typical M$ business). Thanks for your advice anyway, i didnt notice that it has "DrawNode" event, was looking for a typical Paint event ...

Comment: Huh.... it.... wont fire! I am already using the custom TreeView control because base one has no drag-n-drop capabilities... Overriding OnDragDrop, OnDragEnter etc works... overriding this one doesnt. It just doesnt execute, i've put a breakpoint - nothing. What can be wrong?

Comment: Ah yep, found it. Its DrawMode, if its set to Normal the event wont fire.

Comment: I recommend that someone with the ability to do so merge these two answers.

Answer (score 12):

**Fast solution:**

Set the properties:

- `HideSelection = false;`
- `DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;`

Then in the DrawNode event handler simply do:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
  e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

On Windwos 7 this restores the old rendering, including the dashed box around the selection (which actually looks a bit outdated). The text will be white with focus, and black without focus. The background stays blue and visible.

This answer is not new, the others also contain these steps, but this is the minimal needed (at least in Windows 7, didn't test other OS's).

Comment: I like except for two problems: 1) The checkbox icon is cut off on the right side, and 2) it seems significantly slower when checking / unchecking....

Answer (score 8):

Not absolutely perfect solution, but quite near:

```
treeView.HideSelection = false;
treeView.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
treeView.DrawNode += (o, e) =>
{
    if (!e.Node.TreeView.Focused && e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
    {
        Font treeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, SystemColors.Highlight);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds, SystemColors.HighlightText, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
    }
    else
        e.DrawDefault = true;
};
treeView.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
{
    TreeNode node = treeView.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    if (node != null && node.Bounds.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        treeView.SelectedNode = node;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  Although I changed 
Brushes.Gray to SystemBrushes.Highlight

Comment: This helped a lot but when using this, the background color wont be drawn anymore. How would I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Found an easier way:

1. Set TreeView.HideSelection = True
2. Declare the private field `private TreeNode _lastSelectedNode = null;`
3. Add the following to TreeView.AfterSelect-Callback:

> ```
> private TreeNode _lastSelectedNode = null;
> private void treeViewBenutzerverwaltung_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
> {
>     // Select new node
>     e.Node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
>     e.Node.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
>     if (_lastSelectedNode != null)
>     {
>         // Deselect old node
>         _lastSelectedNode.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
>         _lastSelectedNode.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
>     }
>     _lastSelectedNode = e.Node;
> }
> ```

Comment: I write here since "Suggested edit queue is full". The last line "lastSelectedNode = e.Node;" should be "_lastSelectedNode = e.Node;"

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous one but with the appearance more similar to the Win10 standard:

```
treeView.HideSelection = false;
treeView.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;

treeView.DrawNode += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
    {
        Font font = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
        Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
        r.Offset(0, 1);
        Brush brush = e.Node.TreeView.Focused ? SystemBrushes.Highlight : Brushes.Gray;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, r, SystemColors.HighlightText, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
    }
    else
        e.DrawDefault = true;
};

treeView.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
{
    TreeNode node = treeView.GetNodeAt(e.Location);
    if (node != null && node.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) treeView.SelectedNode = node;
};
```