# Select (highlight) node in TreeListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am using a TreeListView (ObjectListView) and populated it with a number of items from DB:

```
class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Child;

    public Data(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Child = new List<Data>();
    }
}
```

How can I select an object (node), scroll tree and expand parent nodes to it (if necessary)? I tried this:

```
var node = data.SelectMany(x => GetChildren(x)).Where(x => x.ID == 100).FirstOrDefault();
if (node != null)
{                   
    this.tlv.Select();
    this.tlv.SelectObject(node, true);
    <???>
}
```

For the average WinForms TreeView my code is as follows:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = findNodes[j];
findNodes[j].EnsureVisible();
WinAPI.SendMessage(treeView1.Handle, WinAPI.WM_HSCROLL, (IntPtr)WinAPI.SB_LEFT, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034714/c-sharp-winforms-highlight-treenode-when-treeview-doesnt-have-focus

Comment: `tlv.SelectObject` should suffice. The TLV compares objects by reference. Is the object `node` selected from `data` existing in the object list of the TLV (with the same reference)? Maybe you populated the TLV data from a different database query.

Comment: It works when `treeView1.ExpandAll()`. In this case, I would use `SelectObject(node)` and `EnsureModelVisible(node)`. But when the tree is collapsed these methods do not work and `treeListView1.GetParent(node)` return null (How do I get all the parents, then to expand them?)

Answer (score 3):

`ObjectListView` has a `Reveal()` method that does exactly this. From the docs:

> Unroll all the ancestors of the given model and make sure it is then visible.

So your code should be simply:

```
this.tlv.Reveal(node, true);
```